# Can I replace the WD My Cloud 2TB HDD with a small SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, nas

With regards to this NAS:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/WD-Cloud-Personal-Storage-NAS/dp/B00FOKN7FG

Can the internal 2 TB HDD be replaced with a 120 GB SSD drive? I don't care about the space reduction. Will the NAS still work if I managed to clone the OS and partitions to a small SSD (assuming that it is partitioned and obviously reducing the size of the data partition)?

Answer (score 1):

It will almost certainly work. You are replacing one SATA storage device with another SATA storage device.

The only tricky parts could be:

1. Does it actually use SATA internally (almost certain, but not mentioned on the page you linked to). Assuming it does use SATA:
2. Does it physically fit?
   E.g. do I need something to hold the 2½ SSD in place if I replace a 3½ inch disk?
3. Does it draw enough power. (PSU's do have a minimum load.)
4. Does the NAS support TRIM? Note that life without trim is not a problem in itself. I am typing this from a trimless setup which has been in use since 2009. But if you fill the SSD in the NAS up to near 100% capacity and keep changing a lot of files then performance might degrade over time.

Cloning the OS/firmware to the new drive might not be necessary. You probably can plug in the new drive and then to a hard reset and have a clean start with the new disk.